# R Format data frame for Time Serie (two ts instead of one?)

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

**The challenge:** I’ve imported a JSON document into a data frame, and want to plot this as a single time serie. However, I’m getting two series. The problem seems to be with my formatting, but I have been unsuccessful in figuring out what the problem is. Data is sensor data measured every 5 second.

**The desired output** is to have start as my X line and value as my Y line.
[Find the data here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3k_xPvRZFL9dmE1VG5PdDhWMkE)

**The script**

```
#Clean work environment
rm(list = ls())

#Set options
setwd("C:/Users/Work/Directory")

url <- "device.json"
device <- fromJSON(url)

#Format date time
device$start <- strptime(device$start, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")

#Create and plot ts
device <- ts(device, deltat = 0.05)
plot.ts(device)
```

[image: Plot of device - should only be one time series, not two.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use `xts` or `zoo` object to store high frequency and irregular time series data. You can quickly create your time series object using the `zoo` package like this:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(zoo)

device <- fromJSON("device.json")
device$start <- strptime(device$start, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
device <- zoo(device$value, order.by = device$start)
plot(device)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. If I wanted to use ts, how would I accomplish this? The reason why Im asking is that I want to use it for forecasting.

Comment: @PhilipHoyos Well, your time series is not regular (you have in some observation 30s diff instead of 5s) what you can do is to try to regularize it using `new_ts <- as.ts(device)` but you will have some missing values on it. Forecasting with missing values is a big topic in time series analysis so may be you should check what people are doing to solve this type of problem.

Comment: Great! That gives me something to work with. Thank you very much.